# What are MongoDB Modifiers and Operators?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am working on a Meteor application and one of the features I'm building is a form that inserts a new document into an array (inserts a shipping address to a user's profile where a user can have multiple addresses). The error I keep getting is:

```
Exception while invoking method 'addAddress' Error: When the modifier option is true, validation object must have at least one operator
```

I have been unsuccessfully trying to figure out the answer on Stackoverflow, Github, etc. but could not find a solution. I now want to take the approach of understanding exactly what the error means - so my question is what exactly are modifier options and operators in MongoDB? From what I understand, modifiers provide constraints on what type of data is returned from a query, and operators are used to modify data. Are these definitions correct?

Does anyone know what the error I'm getting might mean? Here is my sample code:

My click event to capture data on a form and call a method to add an address:

```
Template.editAddress.events({

'click .addAddress': function(e, tmpl) {
e.preventDefault();
var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
console.log(currentUserId);
var addressDetails = {
  address: {
    streetAddress: $('#streetAddress').val()
  }
};
console.log(addressDetails);
Meteor.call('addAddress', addressDetails, currentUserId, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    alert(error.reason);
  } else {
    console.log('success!');
    Router.go('Admin');
  }
});
```

}
  });

My method to insert the address:

```
Meteor.methods({
'addAddress': function(addressDetails, currUserId) {

    var currentUserId = currUserId;

    console.log('user to add address to is ' + currUserId);

    Meteor.users.update(currentUserId, {$addToSet:
        {
            'address.streetAddress': addressDetails.streetAddress
        }
      });
    }
```

});

Note that when I type that query in the console, it works:

```
db.users.update({_id: 'Qdf89k3fd93jfdk'}, {$addToSet: {'address.streetAddress': '12345 fake st'}});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post your sample data and what query you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `addressDetails` object doesn't have a field `streetAddress`, so `addressDetails.streetAddress` returns `undefined`. Use `addressDetails.address.streetAddress` instead in the update. And also, like Joshua pointed out, use an object as selector with `{ _id: currUserId }`. So the whole function should be:

```
Meteor.users.update( { _id: currentUserId }, {$addToSet:
    {
        'address.streetAddress': addressDetails.address.streetAddress
    }
  });
}
```

One more thing, you should not pass the userId from the client. Any method you define is callable from the client and like that, I would be able to call your method `'addAddress'` from the browser console with any userId to update their address. Instead, use the `this.userId` object in method calls (see [here](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_userId)) and check that it is not `null`, i.e. user is logged in.

```
if (! this.userId)
  throw new Meteor.Error(401, "You must be logged in!");
var currentUserId = this.userId;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're passing in the document id directly into the MongoDB query method, rather than constructing an object with an _id property with a value of said document id.

i.e try

```
var currentUserId = { _id: currUserId };
```

Comment: This is not necessary in Meteor, the collection methods all explicitly accept a Mongo Selector, ObjectID or String as the first argument.